# percentage with significant digits

Tags: r, percentage, significant-digits

I noticed that if you are printing a vector of percentages that are on the same order of magnitude, `percent()` works well in getting you three significant digits.

```
> library(scales)
> percent(c(0.123,0.234))
[1] "12.3%" "23.4%"

>percent(c(0.00123,0.00234))
[1] "0.123%" "0.234%"
```

But if your percentages are of different orders of magnitude, `percent` will pick the precision that works for the largest element -- not helpful in my use case.

```
> percent(c(0.123,0.00234))
[1] "12.3%" "0.2%"
```

How can I get three significant figures for each percent when they are of different orders of magnitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` to consider each element separately.

```
> sapply(c(0.123,0.00234), percent)
[1] "12.3%"  "0.234%"
```

Answer (score 0):

percent only allows you to see up to 3 digits, but if you want more digits, what you can do is:

```
> test <- c(123.46644, 139.23424646)
> test <- paste(test*100, "%", sep = "")
> test
[1] "12346.644%"    "13923.424646%"
```